# Buscador en Jetstream

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, laravel-jetstream

Estoy realizando un recetario tipo pinteres en laravel-jetstream, en donde los usuarios puedan buscar por usuario o recetas, pero no tengo idea de como realizar esa búsqueda, estaba consultando con el where o el orwhere.

[image: Buscador]

[image: Searchcotroller]

[image: Tabla User]

[image: Tabla post]

[image: Tabla User]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.